# How to prevent sending empty values of form when submitting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Ant form in a React app, where some fields are required and some not. My problem is that when not required field is empty, backend sends the validation error. My question is, is there a way to NOT TO SEND the value of not required field if there is no value?

Screenshot of the current object that is sent:

[image]

My code for form submission:

```
  const submitHandler = async (val: any) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      let res: any = await API.put(`recipients/${pid}`, {
        ...val,
        user_id: loggedInUser.id,
        type: type,
      });
      setLoading(false);
      message.success("Benutzer erfolgreich aktualisiert");
      setError("");
    } catch (error: any) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(error?.response.data.message);
      message.error(error?.response.data.message);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove properties with empty value from that `val` before sending it to the back end. A way  is doing it so:

```
let res = await API.put(`recipients/${pid}`, {
  ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(val).filter(([_, v]) => v)),
  user_id: loggedInUser.id,
  type: type,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

idk about typescript, but this is how i would do in javascript:

```js
const submitHandler = async (val: any) => {
    ...
    for (let key in val) {
        if(!val[key]) delete val[key];
    }
    ...
};
```